# Redis-Py AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I get this error while trying to load data into Redis in Python.

This is the code:

```
 zkey = 'test'
 k = 15648
 nval = '15648-barry'
 redis.zadd(zkey, k, nval)
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 131, in main
    redis.zadd(zkey, k, nval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 2320, in zadd
    for pair in iteritems(mapping):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/_compat.py", line 122, in iteritems
    return iter(x.items())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I found this issue on Github:
https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/1014

The issue is closed and the solution should be installing RQ 0.13
I ran:

```
sudo pip3 install rq
```

and it succesfully installed.
Then restarted redis-server.

However I'm still getting the same error.

Is there another solution to this problem?

Specs:

```
Python 3.6.7
RQ 0.13
Redis-Server 4.0.9
Pip3 redis 3.1.0
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: Did you try to install redis < 3?

Comment: @SergeyPugach No this didn't work, I tried this https://devhacksandgoodies.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/ubuntudebian-how-to-install-specific-version-of-redis-server/comment-page-1/
But get E: Version '2:2.8.12-1chl1~precise1' for 'redis-server' was not found.
On another server I have redis-server 2.8.4 where the above code does work.
I also tried the current stable version via https://redis.io/topics/quickstart#redis-quick-start
But I got the same error.
Although I can continue if an older version can be installed, I would like it to work with an up-to-date version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not install install anything new.
Based upon the errors, and going to the specified file, you will find this:

```
# "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py"
def zadd(self, name, mapping, nx=False, xx=False, ch=False, incr=False):
```

They need names & scores to be passed as a dictionary.
Here, `mapping` is a dictionary of names -> scores.
Proceed like this:

```
zkey = 'test'
dict = {}
dict['15648-barry'] = 15648
redis.zadd(zkey,dict)
```

Comment: Don't have it installed right now. However your answer should be correct since the error is pretty clear, now I see my question again.

Comment: This answer overwrites python keywords, which might mess up scripts or interactive shells.

Answer (score 0):

ok you could use pandas.Dataframe.todict()